# Postgres: Building a check constraint for a json column

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to check as a constraint if the root keys of a jsonb document consists of any text elements like array['likes','interests','activities','movies','music','television']

```
create table foo(
    bar_json jsonb,
    constraint baz check(jsonb_object_keys(bar_json)::text[] @> array['likes','interests','activities','movies','music','television'])
);
```

The one above doesn't work. Can you help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This can be nicer achieved by using available [JSON operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in Postgres.

Specifically for your use:

> `?|`: Do any of these key/element strings exist?

```
create table foo(
    bar_json jsonb,
    constraint baz check(bar_json ?| array['likes','interests','activities','movies','music','television'])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `jsonb_object_keys(jsonb)` returns set, while an expression in `check` cannot return set.
Your try to cast `jsonb_object_keys(jsonb)::text[]` is incorrect, you need an aggregate. 
Create a boolean function using the aggregate function `bool_and()` and use it as `check` expression:

```
create or replace function check_bar_json(val jsonb)
returns boolean language sql as $$
    select 
        bool_and(elem = any(array['likes','interests','activities','movies','music','television']))
    from
        jsonb_object_keys(val) elem
$$;

create table foo(
    bar_json jsonb,
    constraint baz check(check_bar_json(bar_json))
);
```

Comment: Is it possible without a function?

Comment: Practically a function is necessary. One can try to parse the jsonb value as text, but this is too complicated and not worthwhile.